# using services from android_map_manager and other rapps

Tags: ros, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having some trouble. I have found a resource online for the 'android_map_manager', for example.

http://wiki.ros.org/android_map_manager

I have figured out how to start the app from my program. Now I would like to use some of the services that the online resource says are available to me. I cannot see them (they are services) when I type 'rossrv list' and when I try to access them from my program I get a message like this:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1391876649.155091] [Client 0] [id: call_service:/android/list_maps:31] call_service InvalidServiceException: Service /android/list_maps does not exist
```

I feel though that this should work, as I know the app manager is running. I have this in my logs:

```
[WARN] [WallTime: 1391877076.029768] App Manager : an app is already running [turtlebot_core_apps/android_map_manager]
```

If I could find out how to list the maps, I could figure out how to rename, delete, etc. My next goals are to implement services in the 'android_make_a_map' rapp and possibly the nav rapp too. I did notice that the map_store package is being started by the launcher. Is the map_store package working independently of the map_manager? The launcher that I'm using is a slightly modified version of the 'minimal_with_appmanager.launch' file. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127411/using-services-from-android_map_manager-and-other-rapps/) by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2014-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if that roswiki page is up to date - it's quite old compared to the current android release. Should be close though similar topics with similar types should be floating around.

- `android_map_manager` is just a launcher that launches a `database` and the `map_store`.
- prefixing it with android is probably misleading - the use case is for working with the actual android app, but it doesn't have to have anything to do with the android apps to be useful still.
- `map_store` is just a frontend for easily writing and retrieving maps from that database.

> Is the map_store package working independently of the map_manager?

As mentioned above, map_manager is just a launcher that fires up the map store. Maybe there is more to this question than I'm understanding though..

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) on 2014-02-12**:
So, I've given up on the android based rapps. I'm now trying to manage starting and stopping different nodes from their launchers and see if I cannot control the turtlebot at the same time. This is more like where I started from. I do have the new problem that nodes seem to keep running longer than I want them to even if I try to kill them with 'rosnode kill'. If nothing works I will try to return to the rapps.